# systemctl stop bot выполняется медленно

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, telegram, бот

Есть несколько телеграмм ботов на виртуальной машине, почему то некоторые по команде `systemctl stop bot_name` или `systemctl restart bot_name` выполняются моментально, а некоторые выполняются по минуте, две. в чем может быть дело, что влияет на время остановки бота? боты не сильно большие. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ. Если что то в поле [Service] надо добавить строчку с параметром `TimeoutStopSec=1`